# High charts plot time against a dynamic currency pair

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart chart that displays the current time against euro/dollar currency pair. I am getting live data from a currency layer per second api.

This is the chart http://jsfiddle.net/15vsdy63/25/

This is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

window.setInterval(function(){
  $.get( "http://firmbridgecapital.com/live.php", function( data ) {
     localStorage.setItem("data", data);
     });
}, 5000);

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -150; i <= 0; i += 25) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time,
                        y: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("data"))
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

I have theorized that in a worst case scenario, Euro/Dollar will never go past 4 usd for 1 euro, so in the Y-axis, i am thinking of having value 0 to 4 and x- axis will have the current time.

In my example above, i cant display 0 to 4 in the y axis. Also i would love the area under the curve to have some color like blue.

1. How can i make the y -axis show 0 to 4 and
2. How can i have area under the curve to have a color like blue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the y-axis to show values between 0 & 4 use `max: your value` and for the curve to have a color like blue just change the chart type to area `chart:{type:area, ...`. Here is your example: https://jsfiddle.net/68oe1oLf/

Comment: The type area work but the y -axis does not represent the current value which is 1.18026 thereish and the current value is always below one for some reason. How can i make the y axis display the current value i.e `y: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("data"))`

Comment: I'm not following you here. You said you wanted:
"How can i make the y -axis show 0 to 4 and
How can i have area under the curve to have a color like blue?" if you're not satisfied with the data, you should check if there's something wrong in your input data. Maybe you chose USD/Euro instead of Euro/USD.

Comment: The get data is straight from the Api. I will dig a bit to see what can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind I found it. Your chart data isn't from the api it's from math.random. This is why you have values between 0 & 1